# Remove Mobile Safari Mobile Version Notification Aframe

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, mobile-safari, aframe

I need to remove the notification you receive in mobile Safari in Aframe that you receive when you first open the site, the one that says "Setyour browser to request the mobile version of this site and reload to enjoy immersive mode."

The reason is that the project will be deployed on company issued devices where settings are managed by IT or the users may be too confused to go through the experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable via the [device-permission-ui component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/device-orientation-permission-ui.html#properties_enabled). Notice that magic window and vr mode won’t be available if the site is requested using desktop mode.

Comment: Will this also effect the request access to device motion on mobile Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it also applies. Flagging answer as correct if useful will be appreciated.

Comment: For completeness. The `Set your browser to request mobile version..` message is necessary in all mobile devices because DeviceMotion is not available on desktop requests that for iPads is the default mode since iOS 13. We can change the text if there's an alternative that is more clear

Comment: note the discussion here, which may possibly change this answer in the near future: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4803

Comment: I know it is not easy (or even preferable) to try to distinguish between mobile and desktop, but our website wants to use DeviceMotion when available and fails gracefully when it is simply not present.  Some recent change in Aframe has made it so the message is confusing on desktop: most people don't know how to change the browser to request a "mobile version" of a site, and therefore it's a bump.  I know apple is trying to call an iPad a "desktop" device," but the functionalities differ.